# Network Security Design Resources

Tags: network

I am looking for *respected* resources that state guidelines on how to design my network from scratch in a secure way, including different positioning scenarios for different network/security appliances like *"when to create Vlans"*, *"traffic directions"*, etc.

As per my knowledge, security should be built in and not to be an afterthought. Thus I need to build/design it according to best  security practices from a design/architecture perspective.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ahmed - please have a read of the [ask] page, which will help you ask questions which won't be closed or migrated.

Answer (score 1):

[NIST](https://www.google.de/search?q=nist+guide+computer+security) has some nice resources, as well as [SANS Reading Room](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/). and there a some pubications from [BSI](https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Publications/BSIStandards/standards.html), but i dont know if they translatet thje actual versions.
finally, there might be a  national standard for building and maintaining secure it-infrastructure; ask your local dealer.

> security should be built in

yeah, but security is not a state, but a process and depends on a lot of experience. there is no "read this and the you know it" - thingie, but some guidelines help.